# What exactly do the different "types" of characters mean?

Tags: mario-tennis-ultra-smash

I've seen characters listed as "Power", "Technical", "All-Around", "Tricky", and "Defensive". There may be others I'm not remembering.

What gameplay implications does this have? What exactly do each of those mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mario Tennis: Ultra Smash wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Tennis:_Ultra_Smash#Playable_characters):

- **All-Round**: These characters have no distinct advantages nor disadvantages.
- **Technical**: These characters have good ball control, but often lack power.
- **Speed**: These characters have quick movement at the cost of power.
- **Power**: These characters have powerful strokes that makes the ball travel quickly, but they lack agility.
- **Defensive**: These characters are long and large with great reach but are not agile characters.
- **Tricky**: These characters' shots curve more than other characters' shots.